# Segmentation fault when assigning struct = struct

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to create a temporary 'iterator' struct which is assigned to the beginning of the 'list', and then iterate through that list of structures by checking `iterator->next != NULL`. I believe the issue is in the `iterator = start` lines (35 & 70).

The application compiles without any issues, but I'm given a Segmentation Fault (core dumped) when I `./` the application.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct record
{
    int                accountno;
    char               name[25];
    char               address[80];
    struct record*     next;
};

int     addRecord (struct record **, int, char [], char []);
void    printAllRecords(struct record *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct record ** start;
    start = NULL;

    addRecord(start, 1, "Record Name", "Record Address");
    printAllRecords(*start);

    return 0;
}

void printAllRecords(struct record * start)
{
    struct record * recordIterator;

    /* Allocate the required memory and return a pointer to it */
    recordIterator = malloc(sizeof(struct record));

    /* Start at the beginning */
    recordIterator = start;

    printf("\n\n%10s %20s %20s\n", "accountno", "Name", "Address");

    while (recordIterator != NULL)
    {
        printf("%10d %20s %20s\n", recordIterator->accountno, recordIterator->name, recordIterator->address);
        recordIterator = recordIterator->next;
    }
}

int addRecord (struct record ** start, int accountno, char name[], char address[])
{
    struct record * newRecord;

    /* Allocate the required memory and return a pointer to it */
    newRecord = malloc(sizeof(struct record));

    /* Assign values to the new record */
    newRecord->accountno = accountno;
    strcpy(newRecord->name, name);
    strcpy(newRecord->address, address);

    if (start == NULL)
    {
        start = &newRecord;
    }
    else
    {
        struct record * recordIterator;

        /* Allocate the required memory and return a pointer to it */
        recordIterator = malloc(sizeof(struct record));

        /* Start at the beginning */
        recordIterator = *start;

        while (recordIterator->next != NULL)
        {
            recordIterator = recordIterator->next;
        }

        recordIterator->next = newRecord;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `start` in `addRecord` is a local copy. That change won't be reflected after the function returns.

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating memory only to throw it away immediately? Your program leaks memory... bad

Comment: There is no reason why `start` should be a pointer-to-pointer in main. Declare it as a plain pointer, then pass its address to the function.

Comment: @SelçukCihan Oh, right. So I should update the pointer: `*start = newRecord;`?

Comment: @StoryTeller How would you suggest I do this? `if (start->next != NULL) ...` ?

Comment: @kneeki - If you use a pointer to iterate over the elements in a linked list (a perfectly reasonable thing to do), there should never be a need to start the iteration by allocating a new node for it to point at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare `start` to be a pointer as in

`struct record * start;`

And then you can call the method by `addRecord(&start, ...)`.

Inside the method:

```
int addRecord (struct record ** start, int accountno, char name[], char address[])
{
    struct record * newRecord;

    /* Allocate the required memory and return a pointer to it */
    newRecord = malloc(sizeof(struct record));

    /* Assign values to the new record */
    newRecord->accountno = accountno;
    strcpy(newRecord->name, name);
    strcpy(newRecord->address, address);

    if (*start == NULL)
    {
        *start = newRecord;
    }
```

When passing pointers around, within a function, remember that what you can permanently modify is **the value that occupies an address**, not the address itself. Here in the modified version, the value of `start` is not changed (which we can not do anyway... the change won't be reflected as the method returns), however we are modifying the value that `start` points to.

Comment: That was the problem. Along with assigning `struct record ** start` issue in main (changed to `struct record * start`).

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
addRecord(start, 1, "Record Name", "Record Address");
```

won't modify `start`. Therefore  `start` is still `NULL` when you call `printAllRecords`.